# What Filesystem to use when working between Ubuntu & Mac?

Tags: filesystem, macosx

If I want to share files (locally, not over network) , what filesystem do I use?

Comment: Uhmm... NTFS?, ext4 doesn't work in OSX (i think), and HFS+ doesn't allow writing in Ubuntu.

Comment: @UriHerrera, I think that post is for network sharing? I need a local one. I use dual boot so I want to be able to access (with write) whichever OS I am in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get various opinions on this, but, unless you need to share large files ( > 4 gb) , FAT (vfat on Ubuntu) is a great option, supported on both OS out of the box.

Comment: FAT shouldn't be an option...

Comment: There is a reason why flash drivers are formatted to FAT by the manufacturer, works out of the box on the widest range of OS.

Comment: VFAT on USB key works for me, exchanging data between Ubuntu and MacOSX. Both ends automount. "FAT shouldn't be an option" you shouldn't tell us not to use something that works.

Comment: Yes, I am using a HDD. Idealy, I should have a large (ie. ~1TB) storage partition where both OS can read/write

Comment: @waltinator USBs are not Mechanical Hard Drives... again.. there's a difference you know. As i explicitly said it's not a very good idea to use a hard drive formatted in FAT, and NTFS also works out of the box in OSX and Ubuntu.